# Generating confidence interval for precision recall curve

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, statistics, confidence-interval

I have predictions from a trained model and I can generate a precision-recall curve for the data pretty easily, and thus, also the area under the precision-recall curve (AUPRC). However, I'm trying to also generate a 95% confidence interval for the data, which I'm having a hard time finding something for. I've looked in sklearn for python and pROC package for R (which does have some usage for PR, just not AUPRC), but I'm not finding anything outside of some pretty high level academic papers which go pretty far above my head.

Does anyone know a good library or could help me find the code to calculate a 95% confidence interval for AUPRC?

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't seen an existing library doing this, so I assume you'll need to implement it yourself. No worries, it is not that hard.

I see three possible approaches:

1. Exact confidence interval: interpret FN/FP as sampled from binomial distributions with probability Precision or Recall. Use binomial CDF to estimate exact intervals. This one is the most tedious but will work even with smaller samples.
2. Use normal approximations: basically the same as before but use normal quantiles instead of binomial. Will generate pretty much the same result as (1) if there is 100+ data points
3. Repeat classification on 1000 random holdout sets, use empirical precision and recall distribution for confidence intervals. This one is the easiest to implement, but will take a lot more computing.

**UPD:** some hints on implementation:

- Precision is TP/(TP+FP), ie a probability of ground truth positive for a positive predictions
- Recall is TP/(TP+FN), ie a probability of a positive prediction for a ground truth positive.

Since we're the text below will involve multiple probabilities, I'll refere to these two as PR (for Precision or Recall)

The task of getting confidence interval for both is exactly the same. We are basically trying to estimate *p* of a Bernoulli variable (like a chance of heads in a coin flip). The number of positive outcomes in a series of flips is the same (TP) in both cases. The only difference is the number of attempts (the denominator, which I'll refer as *n* further on).

So, we need to relate value of PR to the probability of observed outcome.
We want to find some interval of PR values such that the probability of observed outcome is higher than some *alpha*.
Using Bernoulli distribution we can estimate probability of the observed outcome (*P*) depending on the chance of positive flip PR (*p*):

```
P = (n! / (tp! * (n-tp)!)) * (p ** tp) * ((1-p) ** (n-tp))
```

Taking cumulative and inverting this for *p* is the option 1 above. As I mentioned, it's tedious (but not impossible.

Approach 2 is to use the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), which basically says that sum of random variables closely follows normal distribution.
Given that variance of Bernoully distribution is `p * (1-p)`, and variance of sum is inversely proportional to *n*, we can find the standard deviation of sum. Now, with probability 1-alpha, p should be in the range `p_hat +/- z_score * standard_deviation_of_sum`.

Finally, implementation:

```
# we'll need this for z-score
from scipy.stats import norm

def ci(tp, n, alpha=0.05):
    """ Estimates confidence interval for Bernoulli p
    Args:
      tp: number of positive outcomes, TP in this case
      n: number of attemps, TP+FP for Precision, TP+FN for Recall
      alpha: confidence level
    Returns:
      Tuple[float, float]: lower and upper bounds of the confidence interval
    """
    p_hat = float(tp) / n
    z_score = norm.isf(alpha * 0.5)  # two sides, so alpha/2 on each side
    variance_of_sum = p_hat * (1-p_hat) / n
    std = variance_of_sum ** 0.5
    return p_hat - z_score * std, p_hat + z_score * std
```

**UPD2:** calculating AUC CI

`sklearn.metrics.auc` expects two vectors, `x` and `y` values. Here precision and recall can be used interchangeably. I.e., `x` is a vector of estimated precision values and `y` is upper/lower bound of recall, or vice versa - `x` is estimated recall values and `y` is upper or lower bound of precision.

Without sklearn, it can be roughly approximated this way:

```
# assuming data is a list of (upper_precision, precision, lower precision, upper_recall, recall, lower_recall)

auc = 0
sort(data, key=lambda x: x[1])  # sort by precision
last_point = (0, 0)  # last values of x,y
for up, p, lp, ur, r, lr in data:
    # whatever was used to sort should come first
    new_point = (p, ur)  # or (r, up) for upper bound; (p, lr), (r, lp) for lower bound
    dx = new_point[0] - last_point[0]
    y = last_point[1]
    auc += dx * last_point[1] + dx * (new_point[1] - last_point[1]) * 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you Marat! I appreciate the guidance so far! I think option 2 will be the way that I proceed, as I have 10s of thousands of data points. As for actually going about the implementation, would you be able to elaborate a bit more on the specifics about how I would go about doing this? It's been quite a while since I've really done any statistics, so some of the things that you mentioned or that I saw in searches related to your suggestions are either new or been a while since I have thought about. Thanks for your help so far, though!

Comment: I updated the answer with a bit of explanation and implementation. As I mentioned, it is rather simple (could be a one-liner)

Comment: thank you for this! I have a question though: would I be able to use something like sklearn to calculate the area under the curves for the found values?

For example, I can use 
```
from sklearn.metrics import auc
auprc = auc(recall, precision)
```
to calculate the area under this curve. Is it fundamentally sound to calculate the upper and lower bounds of precision and recall and then pass this to auc() to calculate the CI for the area under the precision-recall curve?

I really appreciate how helpful you have been!

Comment: Sorry, I accidently, hit send before I was finished typing out my full thought. Please see that previous comment to see where I was trying to get to before I hit send prematurely

Comment: no, you cannot generate AUC confidence interval this way as it will be too conservative. Let me think about it

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!

Comment: I was wrong, this is the right way to go. Calculating AUC using upper/lower bounds will give exactly the confidence interval with the given alpha

Comment: You are the man, @Marat! Thank you for how helpful you have been on this!!

Comment: so I'm sorry to keep bugging you with this, but I have run into a problem and was hoping to get some more guidance. The sklearn module, auc, expects an two vectors, one of true labels and the other the probability of a predicted positive class. So while I can generate the confidence interval for precision and confidence interval for recall, I don't really have a way to calculate the area under a curve. 

Is there something that I'm missing for this? Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect this